# Assign value to a new variable obtained from an old one

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

I would like to assign a specific value to a new variable obtained from an old one. In my case I have this datatable.

```
 $ date     : Date, format: "2018-01-05" "2018-01-06" "2018-01-07" ...
 $ price    : num  100 110 120 ...
 $ Sentiment: int  -2 3 0 ...
```

I would like to add the new variable called "tot_sentiment" and assign the "negative" value if the value of the Sentiment variable is negative, "positive" if the value of the Sentiment variable is positive and "neutral" if the value of the Sentiment variable is zero.

expected output:

```
 $ date     : Date, format: "2018-01-05" "2018-01-06" "2018-01-07" ...
 $ price    : num  100 110 120 ...
 $ Sentiment: int  -2 3 0 ...
 $ tot_sentiment: char  negative positive neutral ...
```

I tried this code:

```
new_dt<- dt %>% mutate(tot_sentiment = sum(Sentiment)....blablabla.....)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `ifelse` and `case_when` from `dplyr`. However, you can directly use `sign` and subset the values

```
df$tot_sentiment <- c("negative", "neutral", "positive")[sign(df$b) + 2]

df
#  a  b tot_sentiment
#1 a -2      negative
#2 b  0       neutral
#3 c  1      positive
#4 d  2      positive
#5 e -5      negative
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:5], b = c(-2, 0, 1, 2, -5))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `factor` to change the levels on the `sign`ed column

```
df$tot_sentiment <-  factor(sign(df$b), levels = -1:1, 
       labels = c("negative", "neutral", "positive"))
df
#  a  b tot_sentiment
#1 a -2      negative
#2 b  0       neutral
#3 c  1      positive
#4 d  2      positive
#5 e -5      negative
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:5], b = c(-2, 0, 1, 2, -5))
```